# pass session user value to procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have created a procedure in user A to get the list of tables belonging to session user (who ever runs the procedure) and insert into a table. but when I execute the procedure from user B. It is not getting the values, I mean the session_user value is not being passed to procedure ?? I`enter code here`s this an expected behavior ? Is there a way I can pass the session user without actually passing it while execution of procedure(it needs to it by itself) ?

**Table :**

```
CREATE TABLE "ABCD"
  (    "USERNAME"   VARCHAR2(1`enter code here`00 BYTE),
    "TABLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)) ;
```

**Procedure I am trying to run :**

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SESS_USR_OBJECTS" AS
V_USER varchar2(50):= SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SESSION_USER');
cursor SEL_CUR is select OWNER,TABLE_NAME from all_tables where owner in (V_USER);
SEL_REC SEL_CUR%ROWTYPE;
VSQL1 VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN
OPEN SEL_CUR;
LOOP
FETCH SEL_CUR INTO SEL_REC;
EXIT WHEN SEL_CUR%NOTFOUND;

VSQL1:= 'insert into ABCD VALUES ('''||SEL_REC.OWNER||''','''||SEL_REC.TABLE_NAME||''')';
Dbms_Output.Put_Line(VSQL1);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VSQL1;
COMMIT;

END LOOP;
CLOSE SEL_CUR;
END;


When I runt the procedure nothing is being inserted into table.
Yes, user B has access to run the procedure in A.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting from `ALL_TABLES`, which is a view that is filtered by `SCHEMAID` and other (internal) representations of the current user, not `SESSION_USER`.  So, when you execute the procedure, you are selecting from a list of tables that user "A" can see but that are owned by user "B".  Apparently, that list is empty in your database.

To make this work the way you want, you need to use invoker's rights on that procedure, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SESS_USR_OBJECTS" AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS...
```

That way, when it runs, it will select from user "B"'s version of ALL_TABLES.

Comment: Not sure I'd characterize it as a "trick", but you're welcome :)  Please consider accepting my answer if you feel that it best answers your question.

Comment: True its not a "trick". I found more info here : http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_authid_current_user.htm